# Use int instead of char in char array and mask

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

In the bit-shifting example shown 
[here](http://rclermont.blogspot.tw/2010/02/convert-long-into-byte-array-in-cc.html):

```
 unsigned long int longInt = 1234567890;
 unsigned char byteArray[4];

 // convert from an unsigned long int to a 4-byte array
 byteArray[0] = (int)((longInt >> 24) & 0xFF) ;
 byteArray[1] = (int)((longInt >> 16) & 0xFF) ;
 byteArray[2] = (int)((longInt >> 8) & 0XFF);
 byteArray[3] = (int)((longInt & 0XFF));
```

Three questions:

1. Why is it (int) instead of (unsigned char)? I tried it with unsigned char and it seems to compile just fine.
2. Is 0XFF necessary? Isn't the new bit shifted-in 0 because Wikipedia says C uses logical shifting and logical shifting shifts in 0? (EDIT: at least it doesn't seem necessary on one with >> 24?)
3. Can't I just do a memcpy() to copy longInt to a unsigned char buffer? Is it not so because of issue with Endianness? Is there any other reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.**

`((longInt >> 24) & 0xFF)` expression is of type `unsigned long int`. With the cast to `int` the expression is first converted to `int` then to  `unsigned char`. If you don't cast to `int` the expression is not first converted to `int`. There are no difference in the two situations and the cast is superfluous.

**2.**

The `0xff` is not necessary. The conversion to `unsigned char` actually performs the same.

**3.**

You can use `memcpy` but it is not portable because it depends on the endianness of the system. It will give different results if the system is big endian or little endian while the bitwise shift solution will give the same results.

Comment: Actually, the `& 0XFF` is necessary if `(int)` is present. Otherwise, the conversions to int can overflow. Then they have implementation-defined results (and may signal). Masking prevents that. Once the `(int)` is removed, the mask is not needed (assuming CHAR_BIT is eight).

Comment: I don't know if I should ask a separate question here. For #1: Suppose an int is 4 bytes and unsigned long int is something longer. Does the cast to int simply chops off the significant bits without affecting the bit representation? (I'm thinking of Big endian, but what about small endian?). How about from int to unsigned char? Wikipedia says char is an integer type what does that mean? For #2: is it because unsinged char is one byte and the significant bit are just throw out? And thanks for #3, I'm very satisfied with that answer.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I agree. But in non exotic implementations the behavior of the conversion to signed types where the value cannot be represented is the same and does not cause a problem.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Can you elaborate about the overflow? So during conversion it's not that the significant bits are just chopped off?

Comment: @huggie For #1 as Eric added in his comment the conversion to `int` here is implementation defined but the usual behavior is indeed to chop off the significant bits. For #2 yes.

Comment: And about the overflow, the word overflow is not good here because because integer conversions never overflow.

Comment: Per the C 2011 standard 6.3.1.3 3, when converting from an integer type to a signed integer type, if the value cannot be represented in the new type, the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised. So, if the unsigned long is, for example, 0xc0000000, it is a large positive value that cannot be represented in a 32-bit signed integer. So we do not know what the result of the `(int)` cast will be until we check the implementation documentation. Masking it produces 0 (or, for other inputs, something from 0 to 0xff), and then it fits in an `int` without problem.

Comment: @huggie: Conversions to narrower unsigned integers essentially remove the high bits. Conversions to signed integers may vary from implementation to implementation.